# JHipster MongoDB connection authorization

Tags: mongodb, jhipster

I have problem with connection of the JHipster generated application to the secured mongodb instance. I have created mongodb user for database and granted readWrite role to it.

```
> show users
{
    "_id" : "jhipster.jhipster",
    "user" : "jhipster",
    "db" : "jhipster",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "jhipster"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the generated application I have added in application-dev.yml file configuration preferences for mongodb like so:

```
server:
    port: 8080

spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
    data:
        mongodb:
            host: localhost
            port: 27017
            database: jhipster
            authenticationDatabase: jhipster
            username: jhipster
            password: jhipster

    mail:
        baseUrl: http://localhost:8080

    thymeleaf:
        mode: XHTML
        cache: false

metrics:
    jmx.enabled: true
    spark:
        enabled: false
        host: localhost
        port: 9999
    graphite:
        enabled: false
        host: localhost
        port: 2003
        prefix: jhipster
```

After launching the application with command `mvn spring-boot:run` I get the following stack trace:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jhipster 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ jhipster >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ jhipster ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ jhipster ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 8 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ jhipster ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 82 source files to /Users/grega/Development/sandbox/jhipster/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ jhipster ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ jhipster ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ jhipster <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ jhipster ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
[INFO] com.mycompany.myapp.Application - Starting Application on Gregas-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 20096 (/Users/grega/Development/sandbox/jhipster/target/classes started by grega in /Users/grega/Development/sandbox/jhipster)
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.Application - Running with Spring Boot v1.2.1.RELEASE, Spring v4.1.4.RELEASE
[DEBUG] org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.config.AsyncConfiguration - Creating Async Task Executor
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.config.MetricsConfiguration - Registering JVM gauges
[INFO] com.mycompany.myapp.config.MetricsConfiguration - Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.config.MailConfiguration - Configuring mail server
[INFO] com.mycompany.myapp.config.WebConfigurer - Web application configuration, using profiles: [dev]
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.config.WebConfigurer - Initializing Metrics registries
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.config.WebConfigurer - Registering Metrics Filter
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.config.WebConfigurer - Registering Metrics Servlet
[INFO] com.mycompany.myapp.config.WebConfigurer - Web application fully configured
[INFO] com.mycompany.myapp.Application - Running with Spring profile(s) : [dev]
[INFO] com.mycompany.myapp.config.ThymeleafConfiguration - loading non-reloadable mail messages resources
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.config.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration - Starting Swagger
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.config.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration - Started Swagger in 34 ms
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.config.CacheConfiguration - No cache
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Mongeez
[INFO] org.mongeez.reader.FilesetXMLReader - Num of changefiles 2
[WARN] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongeez' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mongeez.Mongeez]: Factory method 'mongeez' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on jhipster to execute command { $eval: \"db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_ADMIN\"});\n            db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_USER\"});\", args: [] }" , "code" : 13}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) [spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.Application.main(Application.java:55) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mongeez.Mongeez]: Factory method 'mongeez' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on jhipster to execute command { $eval: \"db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_ADMIN\"});\n            db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_USER\"});\", args: [] }" , "code" : 13}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on jhipster to execute command { $eval: \"db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_ADMIN\"});\n            db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_USER\"});\", args: [] }" , "code" : 13}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:131) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DB.eval(DB.java:461) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
    at org.mongeez.dao.MongeezDao.runScript(MongeezDao.java:124) ~[mongeez-0.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.mongeez.commands.Script.run(Script.java:32) ~[mongeez-0.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.mongeez.ChangeSetExecutor.execute(ChangeSetExecutor.java:53) ~[mongeez-0.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.mongeez.ChangeSetExecutor.execute(ChangeSetExecutor.java:42) ~[mongeez-0.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.mongeez.Mongeez.process(Mongeez.java:40) ~[mongeez-0.9.4.jar:na]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration.mongeez(DatabaseConfiguration.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c5942c3.CGLIB$mongeez$4(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c5942c3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e5d33dc7.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c5942c3.mongeez(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
[INFO] com.mycompany.myapp.config.CacheConfiguration - Closing Cache Manager
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongeez' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mongeez.Mongeez]: Factory method 'mongeez' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on jhipster to execute command { $eval: \"db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_ADMIN\"});\n            db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_USER\"});\", args: [] }" , "code" : 13}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) ~[spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) ~[spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.Application.main(Application.java:55) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mongeez.Mongeez]: Factory method 'mongeez' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on jhipster to execute command { $eval: \"db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_ADMIN\"});\n            db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_USER\"});\", args: [] }" , "code" : 13}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on jhipster to execute command { $eval: \"db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_ADMIN\"});\n            db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_USER\"});\", args: [] }" , "code" : 13}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:131) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DB.eval(DB.java:461) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
    at org.mongeez.dao.MongeezDao.runScript(MongeezDao.java:124) ~[mongeez-0.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.mongeez.commands.Script.run(Script.java:32) ~[mongeez-0.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.mongeez.ChangeSetExecutor.execute(ChangeSetExecutor.java:53) ~[mongeez-0.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.mongeez.ChangeSetExecutor.execute(ChangeSetExecutor.java:42) ~[mongeez-0.9.4.jar:na]
    at org.mongeez.Mongeez.process(Mongeez.java:40) ~[mongeez-0.9.4.jar:na]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration.mongeez(DatabaseConfiguration.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c5942c3.CGLIB$mongeez$4(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c5942c3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e5d33dc7.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c5942c3.mongeez(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongeez' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mongeez.Mongeez]: Factory method 'mongeez' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on jhipster to execute command { $eval: \"db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_ADMIN\"});\n            db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_USER\"});\", args: [] }" , "code" : 13}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.Application.main(Application.java:55)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mongeez.Mongeez]: Factory method 'mongeez' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on jhipster to execute command { $eval: \"db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_ADMIN\"});\n            db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_USER\"});\", args: [] }" , "code" : 13}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on jhipster to execute command { $eval: \"db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_ADMIN\"});\n            db.T_AUTHORITY.insert({\"_id\" : \"ROLE_USER\"});\", args: [] }" , "code" : 13}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.DB.eval(DB.java:461)
    at org.mongeez.dao.MongeezDao.runScript(MongeezDao.java:124)
    at org.mongeez.commands.Script.run(Script.java:32)
    at org.mongeez.ChangeSetExecutor.execute(ChangeSetExecutor.java:53)
    at org.mongeez.ChangeSetExecutor.execute(ChangeSetExecutor.java:42)
    at org.mongeez.Mongeez.process(Mongeez.java:40)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration.mongeez(DatabaseConfiguration.java:65)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c5942c3.CGLIB$mongeez$4(<generated>)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c5942c3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e5d33dc7.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5c5942c3.mongeez(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 16 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.800 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-13T18:56:39+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/228M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem for a day.

I still don't know the real reason of my problem (I had the same error stack), but I disabled SELinux and it worked.
(I did not have any notifications from SELinux though)

You should look that way !

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this is not working as I am still facing the same issue, but using the below properties work

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/database_name

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday. The problem is that MongoDB 3.0 changed the default authentication mechanism from MONGODB-CR to SCRAM-SHA-1.

Try this (it worked for me):

1) Update to the latest version of Spring Data Mongodb
Add in the pom.xml in properties this:

```
<spring-data-releasetrain.version>Fowler-SR2</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
```

2) Add the latest version of the mongo-java-driver

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
       <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

3) Set MongoClient specific options for setting credentials

```
Override
    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new MongoClient(singletonList(new ServerAddress(host, port)),
                singletonList(MongoCredential.createCredential(username,database, password.toCharArray())));
    }
```

If you would like more information I have written a detailed post about it:
http://ignaciosuay.com/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-3-0-using-spring-boot/

Answer (score 0):

Mongeez uses the mongodb `eval` command to bootstrap the database. In some scenarios this command is not permitted / disabled. Therefore Mongeez will not work.

Instead of Mongeez you can use [**mongobee**](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee/wiki/How-to-use-mongobee) to provide the migration logic for your app.

This is my default mongobee migration code for jhipster that has the same effect as the mongeez one.

```
package your.package.name.config.dbmigrations;

import com.github.mongobee.changeset.ChangeLog;
import com.github.mongobee.changeset.ChangeSet;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObjectBuilder;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Creates the initial database setup
 */
@ChangeLog(order = "001")
public class InitialSetupMigration {


    private Map<String, String>[] authoritiesUser = new Map[]{new HashMap<>()};

    private Map<String, String>[] authoritiesAdminAndUser = new Map[]{new HashMap<>(), new HashMap<>()};

    {
        authoritiesUser[0].put("_id", "ROLE_USER");

        authoritiesAdminAndUser[0].put("_id", "ROLE_USER");
        authoritiesAdminAndUser[1].put("_id", "ROLE_ADMIN");
    }

    @ChangeSet(order = "01", author = "initiator", id = "01-addAuthorities")
    public void addAuthorities(DB db) {
        DBCollection authorityCollection = db.getCollection("jhi_authority");
        authorityCollection.insert(
            BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                .add("_id", "ROLE_ADMIN")
                .get());
        authorityCollection.insert(
            BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
                .add("_id", "ROLE_USER")
                .get());
    }


    @ChangeSet(order = "02", author = "initiator", id = "02-addUsers")
    public void addUsers(DB db) {
        DBCollection usersCollection = db.getCollection("jhi_user");
        usersCollection.createIndex("login");
        usersCollection.createIndex("email");
        usersCollection.insert(BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
            .add("_id", "user-0")
            .add("login", "system")
            .add("password", "$2a$10$mE.qmcV0mFU5NcKh73TZx.z4ueI/.bDWbj0T1BYyqP481kGGarKLG")
            .add("first_name", "")
            .add("last_name", "System")
            .add("email", "system@localhost")
            .add("activated", "true")
            .add("lang_key", "en")
            .add("created_by", "system")
            .add("created_date", new Date())
            .add("authorities", authoritiesAdminAndUser)
            .get()
        );
        usersCollection.insert(BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
            .add("_id", "user-1")
            .add("login", "anonymousUser")
            .add("password", "$2a$10$j8S5d7Sr7.8VTOYNviDPOeWX8KcYILUVJBsYV83Y5NtECayypx9lO")
            .add("first_name", "Anonymous")
            .add("last_name", "User")
            .add("email", "anonymous@localhost")
            .add("activated", "true")
            .add("lang_key", "en")
            .add("created_by", "system")
            .add("created_date", new Date())
            .add("authorities", new Map[]{})
            .get()
        );
        usersCollection.insert(BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
            .add("_id", "user-2")
            .add("login", "admin")
            .add("password", "$2a$10$gSAhZrxMllrbgj/kkK9UceBPpChGWJA7SYIb1Mqo.n5aNLq1/oRrC")
            .add("first_name", "admin")
            .add("last_name", "Administrator")
            .add("email", "admin@localhost")
            .add("activated", "true")
            .add("lang_key", "en")
            .add("created_by", "system")
            .add("created_date", new Date())
            .add("authorities", authoritiesAdminAndUser)
            .get()
        );
        usersCollection.insert(BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
            .add("_id", "user-3")
            .add("login", "user")
            .add("password", "$2a$10$VEjxo0jq2YG9Rbk2HmX9S.k1uZBGYUHdUcid3g/vfiEl7lwWgOH/K")
            .add("first_name", "")
            .add("last_name", "User")
            .add("email", "user@localhost")
            .add("activated", "true")
            .add("lang_key", "en")
            .add("created_by", "system")
            .add("created_date", new Date())
            .add("authorities", authoritiesUser)
            .get()
        );
    }

    @ChangeSet(author = "initiator", id = "03-addSocialUserConnection", order = "03")
    public void addSocialUserConnection(DB db) {
        DBCollection socialUserConnectionCollection = db.getCollection("jhi_social_user_connection");
        socialUserConnectionCollection.createIndex(BasicDBObjectBuilder
                .start("user_id", 1)
                .add("provider_id", 1)
                .add("provider_user_id", 1)
                .get(),
            "user-prov-provusr-idx", true);
    }
}
```

In the `DatabaseConfiguration.java` file remove mongeez and add

```
@Bean
public Mongobee mongobee() {

    log.debug("Configuring Mongobee");

    Mongobee mongobee = new Mongobee(mongo);
    mongobee.setDbName(mongoProperties.getDatabase());
    mongobee.setChangeLogsScanPackage(
        "de.shaere.sharecore.config.dbmigrations"); // package to scan for changesets
    mongobee.setEnabled(true);
    return mongobee;
}
```

And finally update your gradle file removing the mongeez dependency and adding:

```
compile group: 'com.github.mongobee', name: 'mongobee', version: mongobee_version
```

I've also opened a [pull request](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/3479) to update the JHipster generator. Now we wait to see if the guys agree :)

Answer (score 0):

The default encrypted password mentioned in the class InitialSetupMigration is wrong.

Changed credentials would be

> username: admin
> password: user